# Use Angular 6 app with rendertron on shared hosting(nodejs not allowed)

Tags: angular, rendertron

This question is more deployment related than coding related.

I beg that you bear with me as i have searched the Web to no avail for an alternative.

I have an Angular 6 app on shared hosting but this hosting plan does not support nodejs applications.

Using Angular Universal / Rendertron requires the ability to run nodejs.

This is mostly being supported on VPS hosting, which is way to expensive than i can afford right now.

I was thinking of building static pages that are plain HTML and Php code to use for bots, but only for pages i want crawled eg products-info page.

Is this workable? OR
Is there a cheaper alternative to VPS hosting that can run nodejs applications?

Comment: How cheap do you need it to be? https://lowendbox.com/ might be a good place to find a cheap VPS, Amazon Lightsail is pretty affordable too https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/

Comment: Thanks Michael! this is really fantastic! Let me check them out.

Comment: also, https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing

Comment: A hoping to get medium size vps for at most $100/yr at least for the fist year.

Comment: I finally settled on a offer from lowendbox.com that was well within budget. problem solved. thanks guys